# PostgreSQL - why is this statement causing a syntax error?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) AS count1 WHERE date='2019-06-12',
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2) AS count2 WHERE date='2019-06-12'
```

why is this statement causing a syntax error at or near ","?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

need to add `where clause` inside subquery

```
SELECT
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE date='2019-06-12') AS count1 ,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE date='2019-06-12') AS count2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE date='2019-06-12')  AS count1 ,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE date='2019-06-12') AS count2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite the statement replacing the `SELECT` in parenthesis with a simple value:

```
SELECT
        1 AS count1 WHERE date='2019-06-12',
        2 AS count2 WHERE date='2019-06-12'
```

Now it's easy to see that up to the comma you have a valid SQL query, but you're appending further values that you want to select, which is invalid.

I assume what you want is to have the `WHERE`s inside the subqueries:

```
SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE date='2019-06-12') AS count1,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE date='2019-06-12') AS count2
```